# Xamarin Forms - setting IsVisible on control based on whether Image is present

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin and I have a requirement to display certain controls depending on whether the user has selected or taken a picture. I have the following Image control in my XAML:

`<Image x:Name="imageToUpload" />`

which gets set in my code-behind file with: `imageToUpload.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => selectedImageFile.GetStream());`

The image shows, but I need to then display other controls after an image has been selected. I've tried triggers and view model properties but I'm not sure what the Xamarin Forms recommended way to handle something like this would be.

```
<Entry IsVisible="False">
    <!--  I want to update IsVisible based on if imageToUpload has an image  -->
</Entry>
```

Is it possible to get a handle on `x:Name="imageToUpload"` in my XAML page to check if it is `null` to compute the `IsVisible` property on the `Entry` control?

**Edit**

I tried setting a bool property (HasImage) on my view model and binding that to the IsVisible property of my Entry control but

```
<Entry
    x:Name="EmailAddressEntry"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="1"
    IsVisible="{Binding HasImage}" />
```

**code-behind**

```
imageToUpload.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => selectedImageFile.GetStream());
viewModel.HasImage = true;
```

**view model**

```
public class PhotoUploadViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public Upload Upload { get; set; }
    public bool HasImage { get; set; }

    public PhotoUploadViewModel(Upload upload = null)
    {
        Upload = upload;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to add a bool property to your model that is set whenever the user selects an image

Comment: @Jason I edited my question above. I tried that, but the Entry control still does not show. I put a breakpoint to make sure that `viewModel.HasImage = true;` was getting set.

Comment: Does your VM implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you.